# Shiny prerendered on a network location

Tags: r, shiny, path, r-markdown

I built up a shiny solution that is placed in a R-markdown file.
I use `runtime: shiny_prerendered`

When I do that obviously the code wants to create an html file within the directory but since it is on a **network location** I do recieve and error:

```
  Error in shiny_prerendered_prerender(input_rmd, rendered_html, output_dir,  : 
  Unable to write prerendered HTML file to \\192.168.88.150/Main/2.Applications/Program/app.html
Calls: <Anonymous> ... shiny_prerendered_html -> shiny_prerendered_prerender
Execution halted
```

It seems the issue here is that it tries to write to incorrectly specified directory - starting with `"\\"`, rather than `"\\\\"`, for example.

Couple of notes:

- When I move the solution to my local pc - works perfectly fine
- Everywhere in the code I'm using relative path of the sort `"data.R"`, rather than `"\\\\192.168.88.150\\Main\\2.Applications\\Program\\Data.R"` since I'm about to move this to shinyapps.io
- If I use runtime:shiny it again works perfectly fine on the server but this is probably due to no need to write down a file.

Any idea how to change the path for the html file or other workaround?
I have rights to write on this network location - that's for sure.

Comment: Although I'm not totally sure how this will work in your actual code, my guess is that the backlashes are being read as a string somewhere, and as a backslash is a special character (escape), the string is reading it as only two. If you wanted four, you would have to write eight. As you're using a relative path...well, things might change you move to shinyapps.io, I suppose.

Comment: This issue comes with the automatically generated html produced by shiny_prerendered... Not sure how to address that...